# Send cache value into browsers save password field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```
<form name="password">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="password" class="form-control required" ng-model="login.password" required>
    </div>
</form>
```

when user enters password in the login flow. I want to send hard-coded cache value into browsers password field instead of the password entered by the user.

Comment: What you did so far? Can you share your js code?

Comment: @TimaGegewepe i was tried with type=text and masked the field with css property. but that wont work for all the browsers. So i need some input to proceed with implement cache logic.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me -- what exactly are you trying to do? If you want to put something in a cookie and have your code read from the cookie, that's fine. If you really mean you want to inject a value into a form that the user's browser is autofilling because they user uses the "remember form data" feature, this should not be possible. If it is, it is a security vulnerability and needs reported.

Comment: @mrunion as am working on banking application they dont want the password to be shown in the popup on click of the eye icon. so in order to avoid that, i want some constant value to be passed inside that password field. instead of the original password.

Comment: As @mrunion said it is not possible, I think you know why. Also, why you need such a thing? Are you trying to save password and when user enters incorrect or correct password you want to let him login (which is not a good idea). For such a case, browser automatically remembers the password. Correct me if I got your idea wrong.

Comment: I assume the user is typing the password -- why prevent them from seeing it? They just typed it?

Comment: @mrunion As i mentioned earlier it is the requirement from client. As we cannot disable the popup from all the browsers we choose this way. they dont want the password to be saved in any of the browser. if you have any other idea for achieving above functionality let us know.

Comment: I have no other idea, but the browser will not save the password by default. If the user is using the functionality that saves form info then you have no control over that. But I think you need to inform the client that their request is unreasonable. The user typed the password, therefore the user ALREADY knows the password. Showing it to them when the "eye" popup is clicked is moot. But I cannot help further as my understanding is you are wanting to control how the browser does things and this just won't work.